# float right questions

Tags: html, css

Here's the link:
http://www.whiterootmedia.com/homepage_layout_test/

Here's the code:

```
  <body>


<div class="site" style="background:yellow; "> 

<div class="banner" style="background:blue; height:100px; width:417px; float:left;">Banner   Banner   Banner   Banner   Banner   </div>
<div class="ads" style="background:green; height:800px; width:160px; float:right;">Ads  Ads  Ads  Ads  Ads  Ads  Ads  Ads  Ads  </div>
<div class="tree" style="background:orange; height:400px; width:auto; min-width:417px; clear:left;">Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   </div>

</div>


  </body>
```

I would like the green div to stay along the top, the Orange div content not to go behind the green div, and the orange div to have a min-width of 417px. Thank you in advance for any help you can give!

Dusty

Comment: re-updated, much simpler fix.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code in here:

```
<div class="tree" 
  style="background:orange; height:400px; width:auto; min-width:4170px; clear:left;">
   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree   Tree
</div>
```

you've set `min-width` to be `4170px`.

Change it to `417px` and all your problems will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Your using the 'site' div as a wrapper / container - set it's min width to the min-width of the tree + width of the ads - 417 + 160 = 577px

```
<div class="site" style="background:yellow; min-width: 577px;">
```

Then, whenever you drop below that width, it wont pull the green 'ads' on top of everything. If you add padding / margin's into the tree or ads div's, you'll have to add that into the min-width of the container.

Comment: I don't care about the body margins/padding/border. If you shrink the page you'll see what I'm talking about

Comment: Are you just worried that content inside of the orange section will go under the ads panel?

Comment: Thank you george! That clears up a lot, but now I have a second problem. Say there's text in the orange div... how can I get that text to push the green div off the screen. http://www.whiterootmedia.com/homepage_layout_test/